# how to retain particle effects in one object when it is joined to another object in blender?

Tags: effects

I created object A with some particle effects. I created object B with no effects. I want to join both the objects into one object C. But, the particle effect of object A, now part of C, Should retain its particle effects but it should not be present in object B, also part of C now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In object C you can set a density vertex group:

[image]

And you should put vertices from object A in this group

Comment: I wonder if this has any effect on how Blender walks through the mesh in order to distribute 'random' or 'jittered' particles

Comment: Thank you it helped a lot.